# Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive vue-js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to pass data from one component to another in Vue.js via props, but it doesn't work and when I open the console I get this errors:

```
 Property or method "heading" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

Why and how can I pass my data properly?

Here is my html of the child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="balance-card-container">
          <h2 class="users">{{heading}}</h2>
    <div class="s">
      <md-card class="balance-card">
        <md-card-header>
          <div class="md-title title">{{ title }}</div>
        </md-card-header>
        <md-card-content>
          <p class="number-p">2345</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
      
      <md-card class="second-card">
              <div class="chart-wrapper">
                <chart :options="chartOptionsLine"></chart>
              </div>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: "BalanceCard",
  props: ["title, heading"],
```

and my parent component:

```
<div class="charts-container">
      <BalanceCard title="Total" heading="my-heading"/>
      <BalanceCard title="Total" heading="my-heading"/>
      <BalanceCard title="Total" heading="my-heading"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `heading` prop from a parent component:

```js
<BalanceCard title="Total" heading="my-heading" />
```

Comment: This is what I am doing and I am getting those errors

Comment: Make sure that you defined props correctly. Write `props: ["title", "heading"]` instead of `props: ["title, heading"]`